# Initializing a dynamically allocated array with a compound literal

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, typedef, compound-literals

I am allocating memory for my float3x3 matrix as such:

```
typedef float float3x3[3][3];
float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof g);
g = &(float3x3){
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};
printfloat3x3(*g);
```

The above compiles, however I am allocating space for *g then setting g's pointer to a static 3x3 matrix. Not exactly what I want to do if I want to free g.

How can I initialize g using a compound literal after allocation? I tried this but it wont compile:

```
typedef float float3x3[3][3];
float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof g);
g = (float3x3){
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};
printfloat3x3(*g);
free(g);
```

```
cc -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -o test-gmath test-gmath.c gmath.c -lm
test-gmath.c: In function ‘GMATH_Tests’:
test-gmath.c:69:11: warning: assignment to ‘float (*)[3][3]’ from incompatible pointer type ‘float (*)[3]’ [-Wincompa
tible-pointer-types]
   69 |         g = (float3x3){
      |           ^
test-gmath.c:75:9: warning: ‘free’ called on unallocated object ‘({anonymous})’ [-Wfree-nonheap-object]
   75 |         free(g);
      |         ^~~~~~~
test-gmath.c:69:23: note: declared here
   69 |         g = (float3x3){
      |                       ^

(3 of 11): warning: assignment to ‘float (*)[3][3]’ from incompatible pointer type ‘float (*)[3]’ [-Wincompatible-poi
nter-types]
```

Comment: "I am allocating space for `*g`". No, you request the size of the pointer `g` instead of the type pointed to: `float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof g);` ==> `float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof *g);`

Comment: It's not an initialization, it's an assignment, but all you're doing is assigning to the pointer.  If you want to assign to the elements of the array, you need to use a loop.

Comment: `g = malloc();` followed by `g = anything` is a memory leak.

Comment: Your first example is imprecise. Up until C23, compound literals created inside a block scope have automatic storage duration, which means that you are **not** setting g to point to a static array and thus the pointer will be invalidated when the function returns. With C23, you can create `static` compound literals in a block scope, but you have to do so explicitly: `(static float3x3 { ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to allocate the size of the structure, not the pointer:

```
float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof *g);
```

Then to initialize the contents, you can use `memcpy()`

```
memcpy(g, &(float3x3){
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
}, sizeof *g);
```

Your code causes a memory leak because you're reassigning the pointer to point to the memory of the compound literal. That's also why `free()` fails, because it no longer points to the memory returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

Typedef arrays are confusing. It's not possible to assign an array. Yoyu can't do:

```
float a[3][3];
float b[3][3];
a = b;
```

The same way you can't:

```
typedef float float3x3[3][3];
float3x3 *a = ...
*a = anything
```

Do not use typedef arrays. Use a structure.

```
struct float3x3 {
     float v[3][3];
};
struct float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof(*ga));
*g = (struct float3x3){
   .v = {
       { 1, 0, 0 },
       { 0, 1, 0 },
       { 0, 0, 1 },
   }
};
```

Comment: sizeof(*g) - a is undefined, however I agree with you if I put the array into a struct then I can assign the array member with a CL. Not sure why I cant do the same with typedef array unless its static. Memcpy is also a valid method that works with typedef arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
typedef float float3x3[3][3];
float3x3 *g = malloc(sizeof g);
```

The pointer `g` has the type `float ( * )[3][3]`.

And `sizeof( g )` is equivalent to `sizeof( float ( * )[3][3] )`. So you are allocating memory for a pointer not for an array of the type `float3x3`.

And this statement

```
g = &(float3x3){
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};
```

results in a memory leak because at first the pointer pointed to a dynamically allocated memory and then it was reassigned with the address of the compound literal. So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

Instead of using a pointer of the type `float ( * )[3][3]` you need to use a pointer of the type `float ( * )[3]`.

```
#include <string.h>

//...

typedef float float3x3[3][3];

float ( * g )[3] = malloc( sizeof( float3x3 ) );
memcpy( g, (float3x3){ { 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 } }, sizeof( float3c3 ) );
```

Comment: Yeah although -fsanitize=address didn't say anything about a memleak because at first it wouldnt compile. Would have, which is why you dont assign to a pointer until freeing what was allocated earlier. float ( * g )[3] = malloc( 3 * sizeof(  *g ) ); would assign the same space as malloc( sizeof(  float3x3 ) ); works too

Comment: @ultimatr I have updated the line with the memory allocation.:)